# Publishing paper using an open-source software

Tags: publications, etiquette, software

Can someone publish a paper on the mathematical model of the open source software i.e. parameter analysis of the model (i.e relevant to specific area) which is the backbone of the software.

1. Is it possible to publish paper on model analysis?
2. Apart from citing the software, what kind of credit I should include in the paper?

Comment: This seems to depend a lot on the particular area of study, and isn't a generic 'academia' question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to publish a paper on model analysis. I would treat this like any other situation in which I wanted to use someone else's "data". Generally, it would be the owner of the data (in this case the developer of the model) that would do the analysis. In the absence of an analysis that I need (or want, or think would be interesting), I would contact the owner(s)/developer(s) and see if they have plans for a similar analysis or would like to collaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, https://conference.scipy.org/proceedings/ annually publishes papers related to scientific softwares.

Comment: This seems like (Sci) python specific, correct me if I am wrong. I think the question aims at a more general model, possibly language independent.